# Abstract Algebra question: If F(x) is the field of rational functions with coefficients in a field F, what is F(x)[t]?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, irreducible-polynomials

The problem I'm working on involves proving that the polynomial t^n-x is irreducible in F(x)[t], and while I understand how F(x) is defined, I'm not really how to understand really what F(x)[t] is.

Comment: [Welcome to Math.SE!](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4928/290189) Please use MathJax.
For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation),
[mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020),
[main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559)
and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the ring of polynomials (in the variable $t$) whose coefficients are rational functions (in the variable $x$) with coefficients in $F$.

For example
$$
t^2 + \frac{x+1}{x^2 + 1}t + x
$$

Comment: Ok that's what I was thinking but wasn't quite sure.  The example makes it totally understandable, though.  Thanks so much!